# Traefik cannot reach backend when docker-compose has port mapping

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

My docker is in swarm mode.

I am puzzled about why traefik is no more able to reach my nexus backend as soon as I settle a port mapping from within its compose file : I got a 504 (timeout) error instead. Without the mapping, traefils works fine.

**Traefik is deployed on the swarm, as a service, with the following command** :

```
docker network create --driver=overlay traefik-net

docker service create \
        --name traefik \
        --constraint=node.role==manager \
        --publish 80:80 --publish 8088:8080 \
        --with-registry-auth \
        --mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock \
        --mount type=bind,source=/var/opt/data/flat/gerdce/shared/servers/traefik/out/,target=/out/ \
        --mount type=bind,source=/var/opt/data/flat/gerdce/shared/servers/traefik/traefik.toml,target=/traefik.toml \
        --network traefik-net \
        dvckzasc03.rouen.francetelecom.fr:5000/pli/traefik \
        --docker \
        --docker.domain=docker.localhost \
        --docker.swarmMode=true \
        --docker.watch=true \
        --api
```

(Il also tried running traefik from a docker-compose file, but with no more success)

**The nexxus stack :**

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  nexus:
    image: some_nexus:5000/sonatype/nexus3
    volumes:
    - /var/opt/data/flat/gerdce/shared/repositories/nexus/data:/nexus-data
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.static.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/static/rapture"
      - "traefik.serviceext.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/service/extdirect"
      - "traefik.serviceout.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/service/outreach"
      - "traefik.nexus.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/nexus"
      - "traefik.port=8081"
    networks:
        - traefik-net
    #ports:
    #- "5050:5050"

networks:
    traefik-net:
      external: true
```

Everything works fine this way : traefik redirects well every call to /nexus (and s.o.) .... until I uncomment the port mapping!

I really need this port mapping, in order to login / push / pull from my VM.

Any idea on

- why this is happening (have I missed stg from the [docs](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#using-docker-compose) ?
- what may be the fix or workaround here?

**Versions :**

> Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24
>
> docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe
>
> Traefik 1.6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I had it working adding a missing label:

```
- "traefik.docker.network=traefik-net"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend sticking this into a docker-stack.yml like your Nexus stack file as it will be easier to maintain.

Here's an example of a traefik proxy I deployed yesterday which works with port mappings

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
```

Comment: I tried both way : docker-compose or "run" as a service. But this goes wrong the same way. My problem does not sound like it is directly linked to traefik port mapping, but more about nexus port mapping when also labelled for traefik